# RabbitTemplate not ending the spring boot + spring batch job app

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-batch, spring-amqp

I have a batch job that would read from a `RabbitMQ` queue. I used the `AmqpItemReader` as the reader. The problem I face is that, when the batch job completes, the app does not terminate by itself. I am not sure if I configured my `RabbitTemplate` properly. It would be great if someone could help me figure out why my app is not terminating properly.

`RabbitConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("service.product.config.rabbitmq")
public class RabbitConfig {

  @Setter
  private String host;
  @Setter
  private Integer port;
  @Setter
  private String username;
  @Setter
  private String password;
  @Setter
  private String exchangeName;
  @Setter
  private String queueName;

  @Bean
  ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(host);
    connectionFactory.setPort(port);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
    return connectionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory) {

    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setQueue(queueName);
    rabbitTemplate.setExchange(exchangeName);

    return rabbitTemplate;
  }
}
```

`Job` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ImportJobConfig {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImportJobConfig.class);

  @Autowired
  JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
  @Autowired
  StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
  @Autowired
  RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

  @Bean
  public Job importJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importJob")
        .listener(new JobExecutionListener() {
          @Override
          public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
            logger.info("Ready to start the job");
          }

          @Override
          public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
            logger.info("Job successfully executed.");
          }
        })
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(stepBuilderFactory.get("importStep")
            .<String, String>chunk(2)
            .reader(new AmqpItemReader<>(rabbitTemplate))
            .listener(new QueueListener<>())
            .processor(new CustomItemProcessor())
            .writer(new CustomItemWriter())
            .build())
        .end()
        .build();
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
My main method class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BulkImportProductApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(BulkImportProductApplication.class);
    app.setWebEnvironment(false);
    app.run(args);
  }

}
```

**EDIT END**

Dependencies I use:

```
spring-boot-starter-amqp
spring-boot-starter-batch
com.h2database:h2
spring-batch-test
spring-boot-starter-test
```

Let me know if you need any thing else that could help you find why my job doesn't terminate after the job is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's your `main()` method? How do you create the application context?

You need to `close()` the application context when the job completes; you can use a `JobExecutionListener` to detect when the job completes.

Closing the context will call `destroy()` on the connection factory (which is probably what's keeping your JVM running).

Comment: I edited the question with my main method class. I did not have to do such stuff on my previous batch jobs. In fact, if I replace my AmqpItemReader with a normal ListItemReader, my job terminates properly after the job is completed.

Comment: Right, but with AMQP there are some resources (the connection) to clean up after the job completes. The framework can't do that for you but it provides hooks (such as the `JobExecutionListener`).

Comment: Cool, it works now. Thanks so much for your prompt response app.run(args).close() call in my main method fixed the problem.

Comment: True. That will work if everything is done synchronously on the `main` thread.